# Wordpress: adding columns to user profile

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm saving extra user info into the db (into my own table) and want to have it be displayed on the user's profile page, using Wordpress's column format (the same columns used for the post edit screen, etc).

Is this possible? If so, how do I call it? It's easy enough to hack on post pages, but I'm not finding a way to add columns to other kinds of pages.

I could build a table manually, but would rather use a method if there is one, especially to take advantage of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into *wp-admin/edit-user.php*  file and find some hook actions.

**personal_options** - runs at the end of "Personal Options" form table. Parameter: $profileuser

**profile_personal_options** - runs after "Personal Options" form table and before "Name" header. Runs only on current user profile page. Parameter: $profileuser

**show_user_profile** - runs after "About the user" block and before "Update user" button. Runs only on current user profile. Parameter: $profileuser

**edit_user_profile** - runs after "About the user" block and before "Update user" button. Runs only on not current user profile. Parameter: $profileuser

Use next hook actions for saving your additional data:

**personal_options_update** - runs only on current user profile page. Parameter: $user_id.

**edit_user_profile_update** - runs only on not current user profile pages. Parameter: $user_id.

P.S. There is no hook action in *wp-admin/user-new.php*, which you can use for your additional field. So, you can only when your edit exsisting user.